# Difference between Epoch-greedy and Epsilon-Greedy algorithm for contextual bandits

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit, contextual-bandit, greedy-algorithm

I am trying to compare Epoch Greedy in [Langford & Zhang's paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2007/file/4b04a686b0ad13dce35fa99fa4161c65-Paper.pdf) and the epsilon-greedy approach for contextual bandits as in [Chen et al, 2020](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.2020.1770098). My question is that are these the same algorithms?-- one considers minimizes the regret over a hypothesis class while in the other we minimize the expected cumulative regret for the  contextual bandit problem with a finite set of arms and linear regression framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these the same algorithms?

They are different in how we chunk exploration and exploitation. The primary idea of epoch-greedy is as follows: exploration and exploitation are performed sequentially in chunks, either with apriori fixed $T-$steps or with $\ell-$steps (epochs). It means we do $\ell-$steps exploration before doing $\ell-$steps of exploitation or some variations of this dynamically, where Langford & Zhang analyse the idea in detail. However, in $\epsilon$-greedy, we alternate between exploring and exploiting with the probability of $\epsilon$ and $1-\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a reason one should expect the same rates of convergence for the cumulative regret the two algorithms? I ask because it looks like in essence they try to do the same thing- in one controlling the epoch sizes and in the other controlling the probability of exploration.

Comment: Good point.There might be a regime where two algorithms produce similar regret bounds. It looks like an open research. However, there is a hint in Langford & Zhang's analysis that structure of hypothesis space would determine this equivalence.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just wanted to make sure I am not missing on something trivial.